# concatenate two json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have two json file:

F1.js:

```
{
    "A": {

        "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z",
    },
    "B": {

        "time": "2015-11-26T08:30:19.432Z",   
    {
    "C": {

        "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z",  
    }
}
```

F2.js:

```
[{
        "oaci": "A",
        "latitude": "45.979722222222",
        "longitude": "5.3377777777778"
    },
    {
        "oaci": "B",
        "latitude": "46.123333333333",
        "longitude": "5.8047222222222"
    },
    {
        "oaci": "C",
        "latitude": "47.123333333333",
        "longitude": "8.8047222222222"
    },

    {
        "oaci": "D",
        "latitude": "46.205555555556",
        "longitude": "5.2916666666667"
    }
]
```

I try to check if it is the same "oaci"; add the latitude and longitude item in the file F1.json otherwise do nothing.

I try to have this result

F1.js

```
{
    "A": {

        "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z",
         "latitude": "45.979722222222",
        "longitude": "5.3377777777778"
    },
    "B": {

        "time": "2015-11-26T08:30:19.432Z", 
        "latitude": "46.123333333333",
        "longitude": "5.8047222222222"  
    {
    "C": {

            "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z", 
            "latitude": "47.123333333333",
            "longitude": "8.8047222222222" 
        }
}
```

I started in json is that anyone can point me

Comment: Have you make some efford to achieve your goal, or are you asking to get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/xmx5ft48/1/) in **JavaScript** (not Java):

```
var obj = {
    "A": {
        "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z"
    },
    "B": {
        "time": "2015-11-26T08:30:19.432Z"   
    },
    "C": {
        "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z" 
    }
}

var list = [
    {
        "oaci": "A",
        "latitude": "45.979722222222",
        "longitude": "5.3377777777778"
    },
    {
        "oaci": "B",
        "latitude": "46.123333333333",
        "longitude": "5.8047222222222"
    },
    {
        "oaci": "C",
        "latitude": "47.123333333333",
        "longitude": "8.8047222222222"
    },
    {
        "oaci": "D",
        "latitude": "46.205555555556",
        "longitude": "5.2916666666667"
    }
]

function getListItem(name){
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        if(list[i].oaci == name){
            return list[i];   
        }
    }
}

for(var prop in obj){
    var listItem = getListItem(prop);
    obj[prop].latitude = listItem.latitude;
    obj[prop].longitude = listItem.longitude;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Output from last line:

```
{
  "A": {
    "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z",
    "latitude": "45.979722222222",
    "longitude": "5.3377777777778"
  },
  "B": {
    "time": "2015-11-26T08:30:19.432Z",
    "latitude": "46.123333333333",
    "longitude": "5.8047222222222"
  },
  "C": {
    "time": "2015-11-26T08:20:15.130Z",
    "latitude": "47.123333333333",
    "longitude": "8.8047222222222"
  }
}
```

Comment: it works very well, big  thanks , you saved my day today

Answer (score 1):

Using your given objects ( `F1` and `F2` ) this should make the trick

```
F2.forEach(function(_data){
    var currentData = F1[_data.oaci];
    if (currentData) for (var prop in _data) if (prop !== 'oaci'){
        currentData[prop] = _data[prop];
    }
});
```

Result contained in `F1`.

---

This is a dynamic solution so it will continue work if you add more properties in your objects.

---

Answer (score 1):

If you call the timestamps object `t`, and the coordinate list `c`, you may implement it like this:

```
for (timestamp in t) {

    for (coordinate in c) {

     if (c[coordinate]["oaci"] === timestamp) {

         t[timestamp]["latitude"] = c[coordinate]["latitude"];
         t[timestamp]["longitude"] = c[coordinate]["longitude"];

        }
    }
}
```